# Is it okay to start a non-essential appositive with this/that etc?

Tags: appositives

I know that sentences can start with a non-essential appositive, for example,

> A hot-tempered student, James refused to obey new school rules.

I found lots of similar examples and every of them started with an article *a*/*an* or *the* (or, if I am not wrong, with a proper noun). So here is the question: can a non-essential appositive in the beginning of the sentence start with a demonstrative pronoun this/that and others?

Can I say this?

> This little girl, Amy cries a lot.

For me, this sentence sounds quite odd, but is it grammatically correct? Can such sentence exist and be understood well?

I’ve also learned this article https://www.bkacontent.com/gs-appositives-what-is-an-appositive-phrase/amp/

An author says nothing about demonstrative pronouns in appositive phrases that stand in the beginning of the sentence. But use of articles is mentioned.

Comment: It gives the sentence a twist in tone. A little unorthodox way to use the English language to express one's thoughts.

Comment: You would need to put a comma after *Amy*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat, that would make it correct but it also makes *Amy* parenthetical. In OP's first example James is not parenthetical; if anything is parenthetical it is the description of him as a hot-tempered student.

Comment: And what do you think about the sentence “This little girl, she cries a lot”? Does it still have any sense? I mean, I am a little bit confused about using a pronoun “she”. In my opinion, it sounds redundant while the meaning of the sentence is just that the girl cries a lot.

Comment: _This little girl, she cries a lot_ is an example of _left-dislocation_. Another example is _My neighbour's dog, it barks all night_. These constructions place a comparatively greater focus or emphasis on the subject than the canonical _My neighbour's dog barks all night_.

Comment: Preliminary point: Appositives **always** follow the head, never precede it. Thus, in your first example, "a hot-tempered student" is not an appositive but a predicative adjunct. In your second example "Amy" is an appositive, but it's probably intended as a supplementary one, i.e. non-integrated, so a comma after "Amy" is required, thus "This little girl, Amy, cries a lot.

Comment: Though I disagree about appositives always following the paired noun phrase, I'd agree that 'A hot-tempered student' isn't an appositive of 'James' here. Dropping 'James' does not leave an equivalent. 'A hot-tempered student' is an absolute, a descriptive; compare << Dejected, James refused to obey new school rules. >>.

Comment: @BillJ I think the question is: in "A hot-tempered student, James refused to obey new school rules," the supplement is not "James" but "a hot-tempered student." So why is it than in (2) we can't use "This little girl" as a supplement, but instead need to take "Amy" to be the supplement?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't follow you. Appositives, whether modifying (integrated) or supplementary (non-integrated) always follow the head/anchor.. I disagree that "a hot headed student" is an absolute since there is no verb present (absolutes are non-finite clauses). Predicative adjunct seems a better term, indeed that's what I'd call "dejected" in your example. Compare the PC equivalents in "James was a hot-tempered student" / "James was dejected"

Comment: The/this little girl, she cries a lot. Spoken English varies from written English quite a bit. //The students all obeyed the rules except for **the** hot tempered one who didn't.

Comment: @celene Are you clear now that your question is based on the **mistaken** assumption that appositives can precede the head noun?

Answer (score 2):

> [1] [*A hot-tempered student*], *James refused to obey new school rules*.
>
> [2] *This little girl*, [*Amy*] *cries a lot*.

Preliminary point: Appositives always follow the head, never precede it. Thus, in [1] "a hot-tempered student" is not an appositive but a **predicative adjunct**. Compare the predicative complement equivalent.

> *James was a a hot-tempered student.*

In [2] "Amy" is an appositive, but it's probably intended to be a supplementary one, i.e. non-integrated, so a comma after "Amy" is required, thus

> *"This little girl, Amy, cries a lot.*